# LockException: Failure obtaining db row lock: No operations

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

I have a working spring application and am trying to add Quartz job scheduling to it. I've copy/pasted/modified the spring configuration from another project I have that was working, but this one keeps throwing an exception when starting up. I'm using quartz 2.2 and spring 3.2.1. I've included my spring configuration and the exception stack trace. Any help diagnosing this would be appreciated.

```
<!-- task scheduling -->    
<bean id="emailOrganizerLink" class="it.cause.cron.EmailOrganizerLink" />

<bean id="emailOrganizerLinkJob" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailFactoryBean">
    <property name="jobClass" value="it.cause.cron.EmailOrganizerLinkJob" />
    <property name="durability" value="true" />
</bean>

<bean id="emailOrganizerLinkTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerFactoryBean">
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="emailOrganizerLinkJob" />
    <!-- run every morning at 5am (every minute for testing) -->
    <property name="cronExpression" value="0 */1 * * * ?" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean"
    lazy-init="false" autowire="no">
    <property name="applicationContextSchedulerContextKey" value="applicationContext" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
    <property name="overwriteExistingJobs" value="true" />
    <property name="waitForJobsToCompleteOnShutdown" value="true" />
    <property name="autoStartup" value="true" />

    <property name="triggers">
        <list>
            <ref bean="emailOrganizerLinkTrigger" />
        </list>
    </property>

    <property name="quartzProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName">CauseITBatchScheduler</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId">AUTO</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold">300000</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.class">org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass">org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix">QRTZ_</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered">true</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.threadPool.class">org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount">5</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority">5</prop>
        </props>
    </property>

    <property name="schedulerContextAsMap">
        <map>
           <entry key="emailOrganizerLink" value-ref="emailOrganizerLink" />
        </map>
    </property>     
</bean> 

<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:hibernate.properties" />

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName">
        <value>${hibernate.connection.driver_class}</value>
    </property>
    <property name="url">
        <value>${hibernate.connection.url}</value>
    </property>
    <property name="username">
        <value>${hibernate.connection.username}</value>
    </property>
    <property name="password">
        <value>${hibernate.connection.password}</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="CauseIT" />
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:META-INF/persistence.xml" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="databasePlatform" value="${hibernate.dialect}" />
            <property name="showSql" value="${hibernate.showSql}" />
            <property name="generateDdl" value="${hibernate.generateDdl}" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <!--
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy">org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    -->
</bean>
```

```
Sep 24, 2013 10:47:41 AM org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory instantiate
INFO: Using default implementation for ThreadExecutor
Sep 24, 2013 10:47:41 AM org.quartz.core.SchedulerSignalerImpl 
INFO: Initialized Scheduler Signaller of type: class org.quartz.core.SchedulerSignalerImpl
Sep 24, 2013 10:47:41 AM org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler 
INFO: Quartz Scheduler v.2.2.0 created.
Sep 24, 2013 10:47:42 AM org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport initialize
INFO: Using db table-based data access locking (synchronization).
Sep 24, 2013 10:47:42 AM org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreCMT initialize
INFO: JobStoreCMT initialized.
Sep 24, 2013 10:47:42 AM org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler initialize
INFO: Scheduler meta-data: Quartz Scheduler (v2.2.0) 'org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0' with instanceId 'CauseIts-MacBook-Air.local1380034061295'
  Scheduler class: 'org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler' - running locally.
  NOT STARTED.
  Currently in standby mode.
  Number of jobs executed: 0
  Using thread pool 'org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool' - with 5 threads.
  Using job-store 'org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.LocalDataSourceJobStore' - which supports persistence. and is clustered.

Sep 24, 2013 10:47:42 AM org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory instantiate
INFO: Quartz scheduler 'org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0' initialized from an externally provided properties instance.
Sep 24, 2013 10:47:42 AM org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory instantiate
INFO: Quartz scheduler version: 2.2.0
Sep 24, 2013 10:47:42 AM org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler setJobFactory
INFO: JobFactory set to: org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.AdaptableJobFactory@3f5756de
2013-09-24 10:47:46,004 [ERROR]: Job registration exception overridden by rollback exception
org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.LockException: Failure obtaining db row lock: No operations allowed after connection closed. [See nested exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.]
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdRowLockSemaphore.executeSQL(StdRowLockSemaphore.java:157)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.DBSemaphore.obtainLock(DBSemaphore.java:113)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreCMT.executeInLock(JobStoreCMT.java:238)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.executeInLock(JobStoreSupport.java:3701)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.storeJob(JobStoreSupport.java:1085)
    at org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler.addJob(QuartzScheduler.java:999)
    at org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler.addJob(QuartzScheduler.java:988)
    at org.quartz.impl.StdScheduler.addJob(StdScheduler.java:268)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerAccessor.addJobToScheduler(SchedulerAccessor.java:342)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerAccessor.addTriggerToScheduler(SchedulerAccessor.java:365)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerAccessor.registerJobsAndTriggers(SchedulerAccessor.java:303)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(SchedulerFactoryBean.java:511)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:608)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1015)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:989)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:975)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:920)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.throwConnectionClosedException(ConnectionImpl.java:1304)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.checkClosed(ConnectionImpl.java:1296)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.prepareStatement(ConnectionImpl.java:4511)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.prepareStatement(ConnectionImpl.java:4476)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.AttributeRestoringConnectionInvocationHandler.invoke(AttributeRestoringConnectionInvocationHandler.java:73)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy68.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdRowLockSemaphore.executeSQL(StdRowLockSemaphore.java:88)
    ... 35 more
```

Answer (score 4):

In order to make the 2.2 scheduler to work, you need to enter records in the QRTZ_LOCK table for your particular scheduler name.

```
INSERT INTO QRTZ_LOCKS values('CauseITBatchScheduler', 'TRIGGER_ACCESS'); 
INSERT INTO QRTZ_LOCKS values('CauseITBatchScheduler','JOB_ACCESS'); 
INSERT INTO QRTZ_LOCKS values('CauseITBatchScheduler','CALENDAR_ACCESS'); 
INSERT INTO QRTZ_LOCKS values('CauseITBatchScheduler','STATE_ACCESS'); 
INSERT INTO QRTZ_LOCKS values('CauseITBatchScheduler','MISFIRE_ACCESS');
```